# Break tie using other column value and remove row

Tags: sql

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS2Fd.jpg)

I have the following table above. Each year is supposed to have 2 rows one for lgID = NL and one for lgIG = AL. I want to break any ties in the HR column based on the RBI value. Higher RBI stays and lower gets dropped.

so for example the year 1932 in NL player ottme01 should be dropped because he has a lower RBI value than kleinch01.

for 1934 in NL colliri02 should be dropped because he has a lower rbi value than ottme01

trying to do this in mysql

Id like to convert this

| year | lgID | playerID | HR | RBI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1934 | NL | colliri02 | 35 | 128 |
| 1934 | AL | gehrilo01 | 49 | 165 |
| 1934 | NL | ottme01 | 35 | 135 |
| 1934 | AL | troskha01 | 35 | 142 |

into this

| year | lgID | playerID | HR | RBI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1934 | AL | gehrilo01 | 49 | 165 |
| 1934 | NL | ottme01 | 35 | 135 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yearID, IgID
                                   ORDER BY HR DESC, RBI DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. however, for 1934 there are still 3 entries. How can I drop player troskha01. he is in the lgID = AL but with a lower HR than gehrilo01. can ask be combined in the row_number statement?

Comment: No idea...we can't even see your data here.

Comment: I added a table to the post if that helps. so your solution worked for when there's an equal value in HR and using RBI as the tie breaker. Now I just want to keep the player in AL with the higher HR, so that would be gerilo01 with HR 49

Comment: Try the updated answer, I think I "get it" based on your added sample data.

Comment: that worked! thank you, you're a legend! would you happen to know a good resource where I can learn more about how row_number works?

Comment: To explain it simply, the `PARTITION BY` clause tells SQL which values constitute a group of records to be considered together.  Then, the `ORDER BY` clause orders the records within those groups according to some logic.  In this case, each "group" is the same year and `IgID`.  The first record then is the one which either has the highest `HR` home run count, or, in the case where there be a tie for home runs, the one which has the most RBIs.